# New Job but I feel lost

Tags: new-job

I am a fresh graduate out of University and I just started a new junior web development job . The problem is I dont understand the framework that is used at my workplace and received no training .

Since I started  I was given a starter task however its been 4 days and Im still quite confused but nobody has demanded to see any of my work yet or asked me what I have been up to for 4 days.

I feel bad everyday after work and try to figure it out in my spare time and therefore I feel lost at my new job.

Answer (score 2):

As soon as you figure out that you have problems that you can't solve on your own, you should find someone senior who can get you in the right direction. As a junior freshly graduated, nobody can expect you to know everything. But people will expect you to ask questions so you can get going.